# Is $N=3\cdot 2^k+1$ prime if and only if $2^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, primality-test

Is the following statement true?

> Let $k\geq 1$ be an integer and $N=3\cdot 2^k+1$. Then $N$ is a prime prime if and only if $2^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {N}$

One implication is simply a Fermat's Little Theorem, so the difficult part is proving or disproving that $2^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {N}$ implies $N$ is a prime. Or in other words showing whether there is a $k$ such that $N$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$ (Poulet Number).

I have checked the claim holds for $k\leq 15000$.

As for the proof, we know complete factorization of $N-1$ so I was thinking of [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test), for which it would be sufficient to show that if $2^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {N}$, then $2^{\frac{N-1}{3}}\not\equiv 1 \pmod {N}$ and $2^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\not\equiv 1 \pmod {N}$. Then I thought about [Poclikngton primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test), but it requires a prime $p\mid N-1$ with $p>\sqrt{N}-1$ which we don't have (as $p=2,3$). As noted by Peter in comments, the last requirement can be removed in which case it's sufficient to prove $\gcd(2^{\frac{N-1}{3}}-1,N)=\gcd(2^{\frac{N-1}{2}}-1,N)=1$, however that seems stronger than what suffices for Lucas' test.

I don't expect this result to be anything new or profound, I just have not found/proven it yet... Then again, I am not way too familiar with primality tests.

As from where this comes from, I just did a computer search to look for similar criterion as Lucas-Lehmer test but for numbers of form $3\cdot 2^k+1$ and it found a match which when solving the recurrence to a closed form gave the statement above.

Comment: For $k\ge2$ , we have a Proth number for which there is an efficient test. A counterexample for your test must be a Poulet-number and such numbers are rare. I doubt we can prove that this is a sufficient test in every case , but based on your search limit chances that it is are high.

Comment: Of course , we can also use the simple $N-1$ test here to prove the primality of such a number.

Comment: As far as I know Pocklington also works if the prime factorization of $N-1$ is complete. Only in the case of a partial factorization , we have additional requirements.

Comment: Thank you, my main interest here is the test/statement presented here (I am sure there exist more efficient tests), though the tests you suggest might help to actually prove the above. Good point about Pocklington, I will look into it (from what I read it's the "Generalized Pocklington test" that does not require the additional condition).

Comment: I currently check your test. Because two other routines run, it might be somewhat slowed down. Hope I can significantly improve the search limit.

Comment: I slightly extended the search range upto the next prime of this form , appearing for $k=20909$. I continued the program without finding a counterexample for the test , but cannot say where it arrived (I should have displayed the progress , but I hoped for other prime numbers appearing ... )